# Transform transition on button makes child SVG jump position at beginning and end of transition

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I am currently creating a Stencil component library and one of the components is a navigation button which has an SVG icon that scales on hover to give a pop effect. To achieve this effect I put a scale transform on the SVG with an ease transition.

The problem is that when I hover over the button, just before the transitions starts, the icon jumps on some of the buttons instances (pretty randomly, depending on where on the page the button is on the page sometimes up, down, left and right) and then when the transient has ended it jumps back (sometimes not even the same amount or direction as the first jump)

```html
<my-element></my-element>
    <my-element></my-element>
    <my-element></my-element>
    <script>
      customElements.define("my-element", class extends HTMLElement {
        constructor() {
          super()
            .attachShadow({mode: "open"})
            .innerHTML = `
                <style>
                  :host {
                    display: inline-block;
                  }

                  button {
                    display: block;
                    border-radius: 8px;
                    margin: 0;
                    padding: 0.6rem;
                    border: none;
                    cursor: pointer;
                  }

                  svg {
                    display: block;
                    width: 4rem;
                    height: 4rem;
                    padding: 0;
                    margin: 0;
                    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
                    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
                    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
                    transition: all 1s ease;
                    transform: scale(1);
                  }

                  :host(:not([active]):not([disabled])) button:hover svg {
                    transform: scale(1.2);
                  }
                </style>
                <button disabled={this.disabled}>
                  <svg>
                    <use href="#circ">
                      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                      <svg height="24" width="24">
                       <symbol viewBox="0 0 24 24" id="circ">
                        <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="12" stroke="none" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
                        </symbol>
                      </svg>
                    </use>
                  </svg>
                </button>`;
        }
      });
    </script>
```

This problem is browser agnostic and I've tried for quite a few hours now to figure out what's causing it. It seems removing all padding and margins resolves the issue but that's not really a solution. What I find very strange is if I put the sag inside of a collared div and add the scale transition to the div instead of the SVG, the div scales smoothly without the jump, but the SVG inside the div does the same weird jumps.

[image]

Comment: Looks like some antialiasing related stuff. The browser would allow antialiasing while transitioning so it looks smooth, and thus your element is "allowed" to be placed on floating `px` values, but then it would switch back to a kind of nearest-neighbor interpolation after the transition and would move your shape back to integer `px` values. However I'll note I'm not seeing anything here on my macOS device.

Comment: I thought that as well but then I tried the method I described above where I put the SVG in a coloured div and scaled the div and the behaviour still only applies to the SVG, if this issue was related to a fractional origin position wouldn't the div jump too. The other thing that makes me think this isn't the case is that the problem seems to completely disappear when I remove any padding or margin, so I have a feeling this is somehow related the calculation of those, but im not sure how to mitigate it. But this is definitely hard to reproduce, because the behaviour changes with browse size!

Comment: Could you try setting some CSS `transform3d` on your <svg>? That should force the "smooth" positioning.

Comment: Is your HTML correct?  Above you seem to have <symbol> .. <svg> .. </symbol> .. </svg>?

Comment: The `transform3d` by itself didn't fix it but if I give it an initial `transform3d(0)` and then do my perspective shift in the `hover` it seems to start and end with the offset so the strange jump does not occur anymore. If you make this into an answer I will give you the bounty!!! Thank you @Kaiido

Comment: I don't feel like answering about an issue I couldn't repro with a fix I couldn't test myself. Feel free to post a self-answer.

Comment: Is that _nested_ ``<svg>`` required for your use-case? You are giving the SVG parser and CSSOM (a lot?) of work to do, on **2** SVG tags.

Comment: Did you try to place the svg in side an element that has display:flex;? Align and justify the element center.

Answer (score 0):

Inline elements behave differently than block elements when it comes to transitions/animations. Your div is a block element whereas the svg is an inline one.

Try to make the svg an inline-block element, or stick on a block element to achieve it.

```css
svg {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: "Inline elements behave differently than block elements when it comes to transitions/animations." Could you back this up with some sources / example proving the claim?

Comment: This doesn't seem to resolve the issue